# angularJS: How to call child scope function in parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How can call a method defined in child scope from its parent scope?

```
function ParentCntl() {
    // I want to call the $scope.get here
}

function ChildCntl($scope) {
    $scope.get = function() {
        return "LOL";    
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wUPdW/

Comment: Best bet, define a service, inject that service into both controllers. Or use rootscope.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can use [`$broadcast`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) from the parent to a child:

```
function ParentCntl($scope) {

    $scope.msg = "";
    $scope.get = function(){
        $scope.$broadcast ('someEvent');
        return  $scope.msg;        
    }
}

function ChildCntl($scope) {               
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(e) {  
        $scope.$parent.msg = $scope.get();            
    });

    $scope.get = function(){
        return "LOL";    
    }
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wUPdW/2/

**UPDATE**: There is another version, less coupled and more testable:

```
function ParentCntl($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "";
    $scope.get = function(){
        $scope.$broadcast ('someEvent');
        return  $scope.msg;        
    }

    $scope.$on('pingBack', function(e,data) {  
        $scope.msg = data;        
    });
}

function ChildCntl($scope) {               
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(e) {  
        $scope.$emit("pingBack", $scope.get());        
    });

    $scope.get = function(){
        return "LOL";    
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uypo360u/

Comment: That's pretty cool! But, what if you don't (want to) know where the caller scope is (I mean in `$scope.$parent` or in `$scope.$parent.$parent`, etc)? Ah, yes: pass a callback in params! :)

Comment: @user2173353 you're very right; there is one more way: `$emit` from a child to a parent. i think it is a time to update my answer..

Comment: Is it good idea to call to global listener where is somwhere, child controller in this case? Isnt it antipattern and hard to test later? Shouldn't we use injections or smth?

Comment: @calmbird , each thing must be used carefully, that is for sure.. Some prefer using services in similar cases. Anyway , i added more elegant version (without annoying `$parent`)

Comment: You're lucky `$broadcast` and `$emit` are synchronous, else these approaches wouldn't work. There is nothing in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) that says they are necessarily synchronous by design either

Comment: [This approach](http://jsfiddle.net/uypo360u/29/) is cleaner. Pass a callback at the `$broadcast` and you can eliminate the `pingBack` altogether.

Comment: I agree with poshest. You don't need `pingBack` nor that `$scope.msg`. You can pass also an argument object to `$broadcast`, if you don't like the idea with passing callback function.

Answer (score 35):

Let me suggest another solution:

```
var app = angular.module("myNoteApp", []);


app.controller("ParentCntl", function($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {};
});

app.controller("ChildCntl", function($scope) {
    $scope.obj.get = function() {
            return "LOL";    
    };
});
```

Less code and using prototypical inheritance.

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VYI6BvZvxoUD4VNDcUen)

Comment: Could someone explain if this approach is better than the event driven approach mentioned above in which cases and if it is, why?  what if you have multi lvl hierarchy w child controllers? would this work if the obj.get is defined inside a child controller within a child controller as long as none of the controllers have the same function name defined? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Interesting... thanks for the comment, what's throwing me off is that i thought js prototypical / angularjs scope inheritance only applied to one direction only.... child - > parent or child scope -> parent scope, not the other way around....but i guess i'm missing something @_@

Comment: Let me correct what I said which is not totally true. You are correct in what you said:
scope inheritance is only applied to one direction only.... child - > parent.

What actually is happening here is that if you define $scope.get in child scope, 'get' will be defined only on child scope(Sometimes referred as primitive definition). But when you define $scope.obj.get, then child scope will look for obj which is defined on parent scope, which is up the hierarchy.

Comment: How will this work if child has its own isolate scope?

Comment: The question wasn't referring isolated scope,
However if you have isolated scope you can use isolate scope binding.
Imo, broadcasting is a bit messy.

Comment: I don't think this example is possible if you need to access the child controller's function from the parent's _controller_, not template. This example only works because of the two-way binding on the template, which I assume keeps polling until `$scope.obj.get()` is a valid function.

Answer (score 13):

Register the child's function on the parent when the child is initialising. I used "as" notation for clarity in the template.

TEMPLATE

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCntl as p">
  <div ng-controller="ChildCntl as c" ng-init="p.init(c.get)"></div>
</div>
```

CONTROLLERS

```
...
function ParentCntl() {
  var p = this;
  p.init = function(fnToRegister) {
    p.childGet = fnToRegister;
  };
 // call p.childGet when you want
}

function ChildCntl() {
  var c = this;
  c.get = function() {
    return "LOL";    
  };
}
```

"But", you say, "`ng-init` [isn't supposed to be used this way](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)!". Well, yes, but

1. that documentation doesn't explain why not, and
2. I don't believe the documentation authors considered ALL possible use cases for it.

I say this is a good use for it. If you want to downvote me, please comment with reasons! :)

I like this approach because it keeps the components more modular. The only bindings are in the template, and means that

- the child Controller doesn't have to know anything about which object to add its function to (as in @canttouchit's answer)
- the parent control can be used with any other child control which has a get function
- doesn't require broadcasting, which will get very ugly in a big app unless you tightly control the event namespace

This approach more closely approaches [Tero's idea of modularising with directives](http://teropa.info/blog/2014/10/24/how-ive-improved-my-angular-apps-by-banning-ng-controller.html) (note that in his modularised example, `contestants` is passed from parent to "child" directive IN THE TEMPLATE).

Indeed another solution might be to consider implementing the `ChildCntl` as a directive and use the `&` binding to register the `init` method.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this seems like a bad idea because the parent can keep a reference to the child after the child is destroyed.

Comment: This is a far cleaner solution than broadcasting events. Not perfect, but better. Though cleanup is indeed an issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can make child object.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);


app.controller("ParentCntl", function($scope) {
    $scope.child= {};
    $scope.get = function(){
      return $scope.child.get(); // you can call it. it will return 'LOL'
    }
   // or  you can call it directly like $scope.child.get() once it loaded.
});

app.controller("ChildCntl", function($scope) {
    $scope.obj.get = function() {
            return "LOL";    
    };
});
```

Here child is proving destination of get method.