# Calling Multiple Controller from a single controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a page in that header and footer part is the common and view part is different.

The code I written for the `index.html` page is:

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="dashboard">

<head>  
 <!-- All the Libraries & css--> 
</head>

<body>
<header>  </header>

<data-ng-view>  </data-ng-view>

<footer>   </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

For `data-ng-view`, in the homepage I have 3 `divs` each div have it's own controller.

Main controller is like:

```
var app = angular.module('dashboard', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
      when('/records', 
              {
                templateUrl: 'view/homepage.html', 
                controller: 'RecordsController'
                }
      ). otherwise({redirectTo: '/records'});  
  }]);
```

Here is the structure for the `homepage.html`

```
<div id='main'>
    <article>           
        <div ng-controller="FlipDemoCtrl"> 
            <!-- contents to display -->
            </div>
    </article>
    <nav>
        <div ng-controller="HomePageLinks">  
            <!--  contents to display -->
            </div>
        <hr>
        <ul ng-controller="ResolveProblem">
        <!-- list of contents through ng-repeat -->             
        </ul>
        <hr>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**My question is:**

How should I define the `RecordsController` so that through this controller I am able to call the  `FlipDemoCtrl`, `ResolveProblem` & `HomePageLinks` Controller.

```
function RecordsController($scope, $http) {

 // How should I write this function to call the multiple controllers

}
```

Comment: There are a couple of way to achieve the goal: events broadcasting, *uber*-controller, common shared `service`. I would probably use the last of these three in your case.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak: Ok. Please provide any useful link for creating service or better provide me syntax for the service in my case.

Comment: @VaibhavJain : See this link, you can broadcast events from parent to child. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038778/angularjs-how-to-call-child-scope-function-in-parent-scope

Answer (score 0):

Use a Service to share common logic between Controllers. Then injecting the service into the four controllers, you can access the common data.

Comment: Is it applicable for only common data ? In my case all the three controllers have different data. Apart from service is there any other way to Call the controller ? If No can you please provide some kind of syntax for my case.