# Calling child controller's method

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers like this

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
    ... my grid table ..
    </div>
</div>
```

js code

```
function ParentController($scope) {
 ...
 $scope.refreshBtnClicked = function() {
    //here I want to call refreshGrid method of ChildController
 }
}
function ChildController($scope) {
 ...
 $scope.refreshGrid = function() {
 ... its using some inner variables of Child controller...
 }
}
```

How can I call it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, you will have to implement your service function but that's basically grid stuff.

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
    ... my grid table ..
    </div>
</div>

function ParentController($scope, gridService) {
 ...
 $scope.refreshBtnClicked = gridService.refresh();
}
function ChildController($scope, gridService) {
 ...
 do whatever you like with your gridService methods or properties.
}

your factory or service 
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('Gridservice', function Gridservice() {
    //data and methods here
  });
```

you can also use broadcast or emit to trigger events, between controllers.  like if you refresh, also your childcontroller data gets updated.

Comment: exactly so you create a factory and keep all your data and methods there, then share it around.

Comment: I hope that will work. will check and let u know... thx a lot

Comment: of course.  just make sure your data is contained in the factory and also your methods, as it's an independent object.

Comment: Ok Found this solution the perfect one in my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038778/angularjs-how-to-call-child-scope-function-in-parent-scope

Answer (score 0):

With directives, you can "register" the child controller or scope in the parent. Something like this:

```
app.directive('parent', function(){
    controller: function(){
        this.children = [];
        this.addChild = function(childScope){
            this.children.push(childScope);
        }
        this.callChildFunc = function(childID){
            children[childID].someFunc();
        }
    };


})


app.directive('child', function(){
    require: '^parent',
    link: (scope, elem, attrs, parentCtrl) {
        parentCtrl.addChild(scope)  
        scope.someFunc = function(){};
    }
})
```

The child calls a function that adds a reference to its scope in the parent so it can call its functions. Another option would be to use `$scope` instead of `this` in the parent's controller and pass the `addChild` function to the child's scope using an isolate scope.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would have to do these things the AngularJS way.  If there is a method or idea you want to share across controllers, you should implement it as a factory or service.  And then you can use emit or broadcast to simultaneously share this service between controllers.

[Can one controller call another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs)

Comment: -1 Yes: that is the plain documentation and I can get such description every where on net... but I want the code snippet to map exactly on my situation

Comment: ok, great.  so tell me, how is your childcontroller connected to your gridtable? are you just displaying data on the gridtable from the controller?  we can go from here.

Comment: Yes childcontroller has a factory method from which it gets data and with the help of other inner scope variables it display it as a grid.

Comment: you can totally abstract this data & methods to a singleton factory service then. and then pass it around functions or controllers.