# Firing a method of the child controller in the parent controller method

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers in two separate modules (and in two separate .js files), the html is like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as parent">
    .
    .
    .
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as child">
        <table>
            .
            .
            .
        </table>    
    </div>

    <button ng-click="parent.cancel()">Cancel</button>

</div>
```

My objective is to empty the table, inside the ChildCtrl scope, whenever the cancel button is clicked. I have the deleteAll() method in ChildCtrl that empties the table, however, I want that method to be invoked from inside of ParentCtrl.cancel(). Based on some research I've made, although I don't have a working solution, I have these options:

(1) Use a service (although as far as the examples I've seen, only data are shared by service, and not methods)

(2) Use $rootscope

(3) Use $broadcast (with $rootscope again)

What will be the best approach for this and how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you referred this below link which has working demo and it uses $broadcast

[angularJS: How to call child scope function in parent scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038778/angularjs-how-to-call-child-scope-function-in-parent-scope)

Hope it helps...