# Is it possible to change variable in outer scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following question: I have an outer controller (HomeController) and an internal controller (PostsController). Can I get access and change variable in HomeController from PostsControlle r? I know that I can read HomeController's variable from PostsController, but what's about writing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use `Scope`' `$broadcast` and `$emit` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038778/angularjs-how-to-call-child-scope-function-in-parent-scope/19038906#19038906

Comment: I'd consider using an event of some sort rather than reaching directly into a parent scope.

Comment: Do you prefer this feature instead of using rootScope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Parent scope variables are available via $parent so you can change those in the child directive.
2. You can use $emit to propagate the value you want to change to the parent controller. You need to use  $on to subscribe to the event.

Comment: What's way are preferable?

Comment: $emit would be preferred.