# Call child controller function in Parent Controller

Tags: angularjs

I am having two controllers in two different modules,need to call a child controller function in parent controller.Already tried $rootScope but its not working in this case.

Here is code for child controller function:

```
$scope.processSignOut = function () {
            LogoutService.save(
                function (response) {
                    $state.go('support.login');
                }, function (error) {
                    showAlert('danger',
                        'logout unsuccessfull. Please try again.');
                });
        };
```

Parent Controller

```
 $rootScope.logout = function () {
            $rootScope.processSignOut();
        };
```

Html Code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"
   ng-click="logout()">Logout
</button>
```

Comment: post your parent controller function.

Comment: $rootScope.logout = function () {
                processSignOut();
            };
html code:
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"
                                                                ng-click="logout()">Logout
                                                        </button>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038778/angularjs-how-to-call-child-scope-function-in-parent-scope

Answer (score 1):

The solution described here:
[angularJS: How to call child scope function in parent scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038778/angularjs-how-to-call-child-scope-function-in-parent-scope)

In your case:

```
function ParentCntl($scope) {
    $scope.logout = function(){
        $scope.$broadcast ('processSignOut');  
    }
}

function ChildCntl($scope) {               
    $scope.$on('processSignOut', function(e) {  
        $scope.processSignOut();        
    });

    $scope.processSignOut = function () {
        LogoutService.save(
            function (response) {
                $state.go('support.login');
            }, function (error) {
                showAlert('danger',
                    'logout unsuccessfull. Please try again.');
            });
    };
}
```