# child component doesn't get its parent's triggered event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038778/angularjs-how-to-call-child-scope-function-in-parent-scope)

I have a parent component which contains (and it's called) :

```
$scope.$broadcast('searchNoFilter');
```

and a child component  which contains (and it's called) :

```
$scope.$on('searchNoFilter', function(e) {
    self.search();
});
```

The parent triggers that event, 
but the child's `$on` body isn't called.

What am I missing?

Comment: the're not enough information to really tell, post some more code, make an MVCE/plunk.

Comment: @georgeawg I think you're right. but how would model help? the child would pool with watch on that model?

Comment: Most likely the event being broadcast happens before the listener is attached to the child component scope. It is best to avoid broadcasting events. Have events in parent elements modify Model values in the parent element. Use one-way `<` binding, to bind parent Model values to child scope. Model values persist and are available regardless of when a child component is instantiated. Events are transient and can be missed.

Answer (score 1):

`Broadcast`  and `emit`  works in  different ways . Broadcast sends events towards child scopes while emit towards parent . Most probably you missed that . If you broadcast from `rootScope` this should probably work .

See details [here](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angularjs/understanding-emit-broadcast-and-on-in-angularjs) also [here](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the event being broadcast happens before the listener is attached to the child component scope. It is best to avoid broadcasting events. Have events in parent elements modify Model values in the parent element. Use one-way `<` binding, to bind parent Model values to child component scope. Model values persist and are available regardless of when a child component is instantiated. Events are transient and can be missed.

[image]